# Reading a number from the user

Tags: c, integer, character, user-input, negative-number

I want to read a positive integer from the user. If the user enters something else, I want to ask again. I did it when the user entered a negative number. But if the user enters a character or anything else, what should I do?

```
int main  (){   
    int takennumber;
    int number,multiplication,divisor,result,total=0;

    printf("Please,enter a integer number: ");
    scanf("%d",&takennumber);

    for(;takennumber<=0;)
    {
        printf("Wrong value! Please reenter: ");
        scanf("%d",&takennumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns the number of successfully scanned values. If you try to scan an `int` but the user enters a `char`, `scanf` will return 0. You should move the call to `scanf` into the loop condition and check its return value:

```
printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
while (scanf("%d", &takennumber) < 1 || takennumber <= 0)
    printf("Wrong value! Please reenter: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not brute force it if you want full control of input handling (assuming you only want base 10):

```
char buf[BUFSIZ], *p = buf;
char *retPtr;
unsigned long val;
Prompt();
while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf)-1, stdin) {
    p = buf;
    while(isspace(*p)) p++);
    errno = 0; /* just in case errno isn't cleared in strtoul - may not be needed */
    /* strtoul used instead of strtol, to disallow negative number */
    val = strtoul(p, &retPtr, 10); /* 10 assumes base 10 only */
    /* strtoul returns value AND there no failure condition, we are good */
    if (errno == 0 || (val == LONG_MIN || val == LONG_MAX)) {
        /* See if anything follows the number on the line */
        if (*retPtr == '\n' || *retPtr == '\0') {
            break; // valid
        }
    }
    printf("Error message of your choice\n");
    Prompt();
}
```